# Does Fermat's equation have an associated linear equation?

Tags: soft-question, diophantine-equations

When $xyz$ is non-divisible by an odd prime $n$, we have:
$$x^{n-1}=an+1$$
$$y^{n-1}=bn+1$$
$$z^{n-1}=cn+1$$
Hence,
$$x^n+y^n+z^n=x(an+1)+y(bn+1)+z(cn+1)=0$$
Can this be considered as the linear equation of a plane? 
If no, why not?
Any hints?

Comment: No, it is not a plane.  Note that $a$, $b$, $c$ are not constants; they depend on $x$, $y$, $z$ respectively.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, if $x,y,z$ are fixed, doesn't it imply that $a,b,c$ are as well?

Answer (score 1):

To any counterexample $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ to FLT for a given $n$, we can indeed associate a plane. Namely, letting $a_0n+1=x_0^{n-1}, b_0n+1=y_0^{n-1}, c_0n+1=z_0^{n-1}$, the equation $$x(a_0n+1)+y(b_0n+1)+z(c_0n+1)=0$$ defines a plane passing through $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$. However, different counterexamples will yield different planes, since $a, b, c$ depend on $x, y, z$.

Meanwhile, I don't know any obvious way to read interesting information off these planes, or to use them; but I could easily be missing something.